# How can I do a dvd install of CentOS 7 that also removes Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bios, formatting, uefi

I am trying to install CentOS 7 as the sole operating system on a computer that currently has Windows 8.1. However, I am experiencing a long series of obstacles when trying to use boot sticks to do the installs  **How can I do a DVD install of CentOS 7 on the machine, in a way that also deletes Windows 8.1?**

Here is my progress so far:

Per fixer1234's advice, I burned a DVD using ImgBurn. This got the CentOS boot process to start instead of Windows when I launched it from the Acer BIOS Setup Program. However, when I chose `Test this media & Install CentOS 7`, it gave the following error:

```
error: Can't read kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

When I examined the ImgBurn log for possible causes, it showed a failure to validate in the following print screen:

[image]

I am currently trying to download Mint to do a test to confirm whether the problem is with CentOS or the BIOS, but the download may not be possible. It might take six hours to download if the download completes at all.

I am currently trying to figure out how to verify the CentOS hash [using this link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CD_burning_howto.html) which fixer1234 suggested.

**How can I get the DVD to properly install CentOS 7?**

Comment: if you tell it to boot from USB and its not, your probably didnt make the bootable usb  drive correctly

Comment: In Windows 8.1 you can even just burn the ISO file directly by right clicking it in Explorer.

Comment: It's called Burn Disc Image

Comment: Oh, that's because you have changed the default app for .ISO, it will show Burn Image if you set Windows Explorer as the default app. Never mind, it doesn't matter since you've burn them with ImgBurn (which should result in identical DVD had you tried the Windows Explorer route) and it failed anyway. You might wanna try @fixer1234 suggestion since I've seen some vague comments elsewhere about the error message about kernel in CentOS that happened just because you look at it funny. Meanwhile Mint just went OK in anything I've ever thrown it at.

Comment: @fixer1234 I just re-wrote my OP to incorporate all of the comments, and to make it easier to read.  And I deleted all my prior comments now that they are folded into the OP.  Mint might not download successfully as all the mirrors are incredibly slow and thus might not complete.  I am examining you link about checking the hash.  Note that I uploaded a log printscreen from imgburn showing validation failure.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I found the MD5 hash values.  I don't know which version you downloaded, so [here is a link](http://mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net/centos/7/isos/x86_64/md5sum.txt) to the values for all versions.  None of them match the value in the ImgBurn log, so it looks like there is a problem getting a good iso from the CentOS mirror(s).

Comment: @fixer1234 I downloaded `CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso` I found the hash in your link is `99e450fb1b22d2e528757653fcbf5fdc`, but how do I check it in the CentOS iso on my machine?  The Mint download failed, so I am going to start another CentOS download now. Separately, I think the OP got downvoted because I put a link to it from a similar post.  You can't win with these people, so I am following the pattern of editing my posting to show progress.  I have never tried root access chat, but for some reason my account has been blocked from SE chat.  I put in a support ticket.

Comment: Line 14 of the ImgBurn log contains the MD5SUM (starts d59c...).  It's been awhile since I used ImgBurn, but some DVD software displays the MD5SUM after you specify the iso (I use K3b in Linux and that does it).  If not, the earlier link describes how to check it in Windows (there are various free utilities you can download that will calculate it, like http://www.etree.org/cgi-bin/counter...are/md5sum.exe).  Typically, you stick the utility in a standard path will it will be found (or the same dir as the iso and go there).  Then "md5sum filename.iso" reports the hash.

Comment: @fixer1234 CentOS 7 boots now, but the PC does not have enough free space for it because windows is claiming all the space even though I do not have any data on this new pc.  The problem I was having was that I did not understand that ImgBurn ejects the disk in the middle of the process and expects the disk to be reinserted so that the process can complete.  Thus, I was trying to install a dvd that ImgBurn had not finished working with.  There is a dialog box saying this is a common problem in notebook PCs, but I did not notice the dialog until after checking the hash.

Comment: It's always something; you can't win for losing on this.  :-)  Glad you got this far.  If you don't want to risk wiping Windows before you have a working CentOS, Windows has a utiltiy to shrink the Windows partition.  That will create a block of space to use for CentOS.  After you get it working, you can wipe Windows and use its partition space.

Comment: @fixer1234 I made a 200GB partition in windows and am installing CentOS into it.  I have to specify the capacity of the `/boot` mount point.  Do you have an opinion of how much space I should allocate?  On my devbox, the `/boot` directory and its subdirectories total 195MB.  So is it enough to give 230MB to `/boot`?

Comment: @fixer1234 The CentOS installation was successful, as a result of your DVD approach.  I revised the OP to make it more focused on what we actually did.  If you want to summarize it in an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.

Comment: You did the heavy lifting (and are more familiar with the details of what you did).  You should write up the answer and get the credit for all your work.  Glad I was able to help.  Hope you plan to celebrate your success.  :-)

Answer (score -3):

You're confusing things. Boot order of HARDWARE devices has nothing to do with the operating systems installed in them. As fixer1234 mentioned.
Look up the BIOS version of your mobo and google how to enable the boot from usb. Some BIOS may need more than just setting the USB as the first boot point. You may need to a different menu like peripherals or something that allows you to enable the USB port. Even if you can read the USB stick from Windows 8.1 the BIOS may block booting from it for Security reasons.

You may want to look at things like Peripherals or Security then.

Also, if you want an exact answer you'd need to post more information in order to troubleshoot including all the characteristics of your BIOS, Mobo model, etc.